# Tab autocomplete in Visual Studio Code doesn't work

Tags: visual-studio-code, editor

I am trying to enable tab auto-completion with pressing "Tab" button but it doesn't work for me and it always works as Tab character when it is supposed to work as autocomplete. Which setting or shortcut should I enable or disable to have this feature?

[image: Tab Auto-completion 1]

With pressing "Tab", I will get this;

[image: Tab Autocomplete 2]

PS: Pressing "Enter" works fine and accepts the suggestion and I can disable it by setting the following setting to off.

[image]

Comment: Don't know if this helps, but you can press CTRL+SPACE to bring up autocomplete.

Comment: @PeterWarrington I know how to bring up suggestions. My question is about using that suggestion with pressing of tab button

Comment: Oh I see, Sorry, Don't know how to help with that :-q.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Try changing tab completion setting to On:

Editor › tab Completion

```
"editor.tabCompletion": "on"
```

Also for HTML/Javascript you could make emmet setting to true

```
"emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true
```

Comment: Thanks mate, your answer save my day :D

Comment: Neither of these is working for me. editor.tabCompletion was off. When I turn it on it toggles between some options (e.g. div/device) but doesn't close tags or complete anything. Pressing Enter does nothing except enter a carriage return.

Answer (score 2):

there may be keyboard shortcut conflicts in vs code. you should check keyboard shortcuts for tab, especially keyboard shortcuts come from extensions. if there is, you should remove it. then it will work.

Answer (score 2):

1. Open Visual Study Code Setting.
2. Enable Tab Completion
   [image]

Answer (score 2):

I found I had to press 'ctrl+m' to toggle on/off if tab would move focus or perform its assigned shortcut (ie. for me, autocomplete in the editor and terminal and accept suggestions). Alternatively, try 'ctrl+shift+p' (open command pallete), then search and select 'Toggle Tab Moves Focus'.

It doesn't solve exactly the same error as the OP's, but I came looking here for that answer, and so might someone else.[image: VSC signaling what tab is doing atm] :)

Answer (score 0):

For HTML doing both the steps listed by Vinoth on Sep 08, 2019 worked for me:

1. "editor.tabCompletion": "on"
2. "emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true

Comment: Please don't repeat existing answers. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30474869)

Answer (score 0):

Control + P -> Terminal:Focus Terminal TabsView ->Click ().
Or `Ctrl +  shift + \`

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Visual Study Code Setting.
2. Go to edit in settings.json.
3. Add the below code:-

   "emmet.includeLanguages": {"javascript": "javascriptreact"},

[image]

[image]

Now have a fun

[image]

Comment: The question is specifically about how to enable AutoCompletion using the `Tab`-button - I don't believe this answer solves that problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my situation, I was working in a remote environment and my user settings weren't being applied to it (obviously).

[image: environment tabs at top]

This may be helpful to anyone who stumbles upon this question but the accepted answer doesn't work.

Just select your environment and then change the settings there.

Answer (score 0):

You likely have a Keyboard Shortcut overriding the System default.

1. File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts
2. Search "tab"
3. Look for anything where the Source is "User" that is using a Keybinding "Tab"
4. Right-click and Remove Binding.

Answer (score 0):

1. Ctrl+Shift+P
2. Find "Emmet:Expand abbreviation"
3. Set it to "Tab" key. Maybe first set it to any other key. Cheсk. If it's work - set back to TAB.

Answer (score 0):

Choose an option in the drop down and then try using `Shift + Enter` to confirm the suggestion.

If that works you can go to keyboard shortcuts in VSCode (File - Preferences - Keyboard Shortcuts) and search for Shift + Enter, you might see something like acceptAlternativeSelectedSuggestion and you could try changing that.

Answer (score 0):

Well what worked for me is that I went to `Keyboard Shortcuts` and then in toggle the `sort by precedence` button on the left side of input and pressed the `tab` key. Like this
[image]
As you can see the `Accept inline Suggestion` is there but its precedence is far lower.

What I did then is

1. open the default keyboard shortcut json file using `Ctrl+Shift+P` and typing `open default shortcut`
2. search for `tab` key using `ctrl+f`
3. find the one that says `accepting inline suggestion`
4. copy the entire object or just copy this

```
{ "key": "tab", 
"command": "acceptSelectedSuggestion",
"when": "suggestWidgetHasFocusedSuggestion && suggestWidgetVisible && textInputFocus" },
```

5. paste it into `keybindings.json`