# What is the name of the key binding for tabbing through snippets?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I accidentally changed something in the keybindings of VS code, and now my tabbing through snippets isn't working. For example, the import snippet:

```js
import {  } from "module";
```

I can type "import", hit tab and get the above, with the cursor highlighting "module". I then type and hit tab when done, but it does nothing!

Any help on this would be amazing as I'm currently losing my mind haha. Thanks guys!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tab autocomplete in Visual Studio Code doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57841968/tab-autocomplete-in-visual-studio-code-doesnt-work)

Comment: So I took a look and no, I have tabCompletion on. But tabCompletion isn't working. I think It has to do with the intellisense suggestions. I tried changing it to be able to tab through suggestions, but I changed it back, so I'm starting to think it's a bug?

Comment: Here's another clue lol: when I "ctrl + m" to switch to "tab move focus" mode, I can't tab around, but I can shift-tab backwards.

Answer (score 0):

So here's where the option is:
[image]

It was set to "Tab" but just simply not working.

What I did was set the keybinding to another key, tested that, then switched it back to tab and that resolved the issue.