# Pylance not recognizing parts of libraries

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylance

i'm currently programming in python using VS code with the pylance extension, it's working pretty well except i can't import an entire library at once, i have to import the individual functions which is kind of annoying for learning purposes

in the screenshot below i have them set up in the same way and it works in both ways but it's annoying not being able to see which functions are available in the library when i place a "." after "pygame". The problem here is that i can see the first line being fully colored with yellow highlighting the "load", where "image.load" below isn't.

[Both functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xC7X.png)

NOTE: i have also had this issue with other libraries, numpy to name a popular one

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57841968/tab-autocomplete-in-visual-studio-code-doesnt-work

Comment: @mast3r_waf1z -Did you use the VS Code theme extension? Have you used any related theme settings?("settings.json")

Comment: @Jill Cheng nope, I just have the default theme

Comment: This is not because "Pylance" does not recognize some libraries, but the source and path of the referenced classes or methods. When I use "Ctrl" and click the keyword "image" with the mouse, I can find the defined "open" in the file "Image.py", but after clicking "pygame", I can't find the defined "image.load".