# How do I insert a snippet into a VSCode file?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

I've used snippets before but it's been a very long time, so I don't remember how to insert them.

I already edited my settings according to [Tab autocomplete in Visual Studio Code doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57841968/tab-autocomplete-in-visual-studio-code-doesnt-work), but it's still not working.

- "editor.tabCompletion": "on"
- "emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true

When I type the name of the snippet (e.g., html-boilerplate) in a file, no autocomplete suggestions come up. Then, if I tab, it just creates the name of the snippet as a tag (i.e., `<html-boilerplate></html-boilerplate>`).

If I open the command pallet (ctrl+p) and type "insert," the name of the snippet comes up, but clicking on it just opens the snippet file itself.

I also tried ctrl+shift+p, typing >insert, and then selecting "Insert Snippet," but then it just says no snippets are available (neither the defaults nor the ones I've created). Source: https://adamtheautomator.com/vs-code-snippets/

Your time and assistance are greatly appreciated!

Comment: what happens if you type `Ctrl+Space`  or `Shift+Ctrl+Space`

Comment: There was an emmet bug introduced with the last released.  It is due to be fixed in v1.69.2.  That might help you.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72908218/some-emmet-abbreviations-in-vsc-not-working-like-or-using/72914461#72914461

Comment: @rioV8 When I type ```Ctrl+Space``` I get a list of suggestions, but not anything to do with snippets. When I type ```Shift+Ctrl+Space``` nothing happens.

@Mark thank you for the bug info.