# Enter and Tab Doesn't Work On VS Code Intellisense

Tags: visual-studio-code

I started using VS Code recently and tried to do some code on C and Java but I've noticed that Intellisense doesn't work properly.

It suggests changes but it doesn't let me select the option I want with Enter or Tab, only clicking.

I revised the settings but all looks ok to me.

I also tried that solution but I have the same in my settings:
[Tab autocomplete in Visual Studio Code doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57841968/tab-autocomplete-in-visual-studio-code-doesnt-work)

Does anyone know what can be happening?

Edit:

I realized that other shortcuts like Ctrl+Shift+P doesn't work.

Everything works fine on ubuntu 22.04.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found that restoring the shortcuts solved it, it was probably some problem in the synchronization between computers and the installation of some extensions.