# I'm writing a React project, but it doesn't auto-fill HTML codes

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, components

I am writing a React project, but I will write a div in a component, for example, normally I write a div with visual studio code and when I press the tab button, it automatically writes as `<div> </div>`, but this does not happen to me and the html codes are not assigned automatically, what should I do?

I want writing an html tag in a React project and auto-filling it on tab.

Comment: Probably you should look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57841968/tab-autocomplete-in-visual-studio-code-doesnt-work)

Comment: "what should I do?" Type `</div>`? It's not that hard. This has nothing to do with React and everything to do with the IDE you use. Which one are you using?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if you use js or ts but in order to use snippets use jsx or tsx file extensions.

For example, if you have a main.js file, name it to main.jsx. In JSX file, when you write div you you close it automatically with tab.

Comment: Çok teşekkür ederim

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).