# Can't autocomplete Codeium suggestion on Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have the Codeium Extension installed on my VSCode, the extension suggest code, but I am unable to accept with TAB key.

Tried to re-bind auto complete code in VSCode, but just changed the autocomplete from IDE. Anyone can help me?

edit Keybind Troubleshooting:

```
2023-09-11 16:54:15.002 [info] [KeybindingService]: | Resolving Tab
2023-09-11 16:54:15.003 [info] [KeybindingService]: \ From 10 keybinding entries, no when clauses matched the context.
2023-09-11 16:54:15.003 [info] [KeybindingService]: / Received  keydown event - modifiers: [], code: Tab, keyCode: 9, key: Tab
2023-09-11 16:54:15.003 [info] [KeybindingService]: | Converted keydown event - modifiers: [], code: Tab, keyCode: 2 ('Tab')
2023-09-11 16:54:15.004 [info] [KeybindingService]: | Resolving Tab
2023-09-11 16:54:15.004 [info] [KeybindingService]: \ From 10 keybinding entries, no when clauses matched the context.
```

edit: I solved after I disabled an extension from my VSCode called Angular emmit, now it's all fine!

Comment: Welcome! What do you see when you [troubleshoot your keybindings](//github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Keybinding-Issues)? Please paste the relevant parts of what you see into a code block in your question post.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57841968/tab-autocomplete-in-visual-studio-code-doesnt-work/77978781#77978781)
or just copy paste this code in `keybings.json`

```
{ "key": "tab",                   "command": "acceptSelectedSuggestion",
                                     "when": "suggestWidgetHasFocusedSuggestion && suggestWidgetVisible && textInputFocus" },
```

Comment: I solved it, it was a Angular Plugin that's using the same keybind